# What framework access sensitive user data that need NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have gotten the following message from App Store Connect when trying to upload a new version...

> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs.

But I do not use bluetooth anywhere in the app (no bluetooth code).

Here are the frameworks I use: 
CoreText, QuartzCore, CoreLocation, CoreGraphics, Foundation, UIKit, StoreKit, CoreData, MapKit

Any advice?

Comment: why -4? what is wrong?

Comment: I am having the same problem. any solution?

Comment: @arniotaki Stackoverflow has a lemmings tendency. It takes one person to downvote for others to join in. I have the same issue, and may have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Open Info Plist file and press on + sign add new key in info.plist of your project and add this NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription and write value "Explain the reasons for Bluetooth".

FacebookSDK is scanning Bluetooth since v 4.33. This is the description I have picked.

`Facebook-SDK v4.34 contains Places Kit which contains Bluetooth scanning. This app isn't scanning/using Bluetooth at all.`